# Fetch new value from wenzhixin bootstrap table's x-editable option

Tags: jquery, x-editable, bootstrap-table

I am trying to fetch the new value from wenzhixin bootstrap table's x-editable option on submitting the value but unable to achieve it. I tried using `editable-save.bs.table` but unable to fetch changed value as it only have 4 parameters field, row, old value and element.

Following is my JS code:

```
$('#inventory-table').bootstrapTable({
})
.on('editable-save.bs.table', function(e, field, row, oldValue, $el){
    var new_value = $el[0];
    console.log(new_value)
    value1 = ($(new_value).html());
    console.log(value1);
    console.log('new value: ' + oldValue, $el[0]['innerHTML'], $el);

})
```

Following code gives me the new value named as innerHTML inside $el[0] which is a html object. I've attached the screenshot to make it clear.

[image]

But when I am trying to fetch that value using something like this `$el[0]['innerHTML']`, it gives me old value not the new one.

Kindly help 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple, the answer is in the 'row' parameter which holds the new value.